# Renaming files from upper case to lower case

Tags: shell

I need to elaborate a little bit more. These commands are actually for a BBS FTN tosser. The configuration file for which these commands reside in, only allow specific declarations. Here are a few examples:

```
exec "/home/imp/imp/poll.sh" *.su? *.mo? *.tu? *.we? *th? *.fr? *.sa? *.pkt
flag toss!.now [0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z][0-9a-Z].???
exec "/home/imp/imp/poll.sh /home/imp/hpt/secure" /home/imp/hpt/secure/*.[STFWMstfWM][ouaherOUAHER][0-9A-ZA-a] *.[pP][kK][tT]
```

So that's why I want to use that syntax ([0-9a-z] (for example)).
The problem is that the mailer is looking for lowercase filenames, but only uppercase filenames exist.

I'm trying to convert a file from uppercase to lowercase using the syntax below:

```
mv /home/imp/hpt/outbound/[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z].[STFWMfWM][OUAHER][0-9] /home/imp/hpt/outbound/[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z].[stfwm][ouaher][0-9a-za-a]
```

I don't think I have the syntax correct.

Here's an example of a file name I want to rename:

0000FE70.FR0

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In Bash 4: `"${file,,}"`. See [the always excellent Wooledge Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030)...

Comment: Thanks for that.. but i'd like to use the [x-xx-x].. format

Comment: You might be thinking of our friend `tr`, then...

Comment: *Sigh* The Wooledge wiki describes exactly how to do that...

Comment: You can't use `[a-Z]` as a range! It needs to be `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: @jasonwryan It's for `sh`: see the tags. Anyways, thx for useful info...

Comment: Do you mean something like `mv UPPERCSE.EXT uppercse.ext`, but for the whole current directory?

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you want to change one class of characters into another, use `tr`.

```
for f in *; do
    test -f "$f" && echo mv "$f" "$( tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$f" )"
done
```

The script will rename all files in the current directory to all lowercase letters. It will skip directories.  Remove the `echo` when you're certain it does what you want. You may replace `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` with `A-Z` and `a-z` respectively if you only have standard ASCII filenames (note: `A-Z`, not `[A-Z]`).

Alternatively, using Bash's built-in upper-to-lowercase variable substitution:

```
for f in *; do
    test -f "$f" && echo mv "$f" "${f,,}"
done
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what the `<<<` does, please?

Comment: @Daniele It's a "here-string".  It passes the given string to the standard input of the command.  `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"HELLO"` would output `hello`. It is similar to doing `echo 'HELLO' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`, but without involving `echo`.  Here-strings are an extension to the standard shell syntax, but they are understood by `bash`.

Comment: Two questions: (a) what is the role of the `test -f "$f"` ? and (b) why wasn’t this answer accepted?

Comment: @Manngo a) The test makes sure that `$f` refers to a regular file, and not, say, a directory.  b) Nobody knows.

Comment: (a) Thanks; (b) Oh well, have an upvote anyway.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/152741/2137913) from Alex B at Stack Overflow will help you to rename both files and subfolders under a directory.

It consists on using both `find` and `rename` Linux commands. I would only add that the command provided in the link above will modify directory names as well. In case that you want only to change file names, you need to change the `-depth` option with the next one: `-type f`.

Another regular expression given to the `rename` command could be the one below, which I think it is more easy to understand.

```
 find my_root_dir -type f -execdir rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' {} \;
```

Be aware that there is a necessary white space between the `rename` command regular expression and the curly braces,  and another one between them and the command termination character `\;`

Also remember that it will rename every file not only in the directory where you execute the command from (the `my_root_dir` directory) but also to all the files under every subfolder contained into this one.  You can use the `-maxdepth 0` option with the `find` command to force it to only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.

Comment: note: this is the perl `rename`, not the util-linux `rename`.

Comment: I'm not certain that find is needed..  `rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *[A-Z]*`

Comment: None of these commands actually work. I keep getting the rename "help screen" :/

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake with the regular expression in the second command. I also modified the `find` command `-execdir` option so it now runs the required action on every directory where a file is found. I tested it and worked. Could you please let me know if it works for you now?

Comment: Thank you, I much prefer this. I used `ls -d * |  xargs --delimiter '\n' --max-args=1 rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/'`

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
for i in $( ls | grep [A-Z] ); do mv -f $i `echo $i | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`; done
```

And this is an example showing how it works:

```
X$ ls

123123HHHSK FILE_[1-10] DB
FILE1       FILE_{1-10} SQL

X$ for i in $( ls | grep [A-Z] ); do mv -f $i `echo $i | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'`; done

X$ ls

123123hhhsk file_[1-10] db
file1       file_{1-10} sql
```

**EDIT**: We could easily use `-f` option, to avoid using `yes y`.

Comment: `$( ls | grep [A-Z] )` should be the same as the glob `*[A-Z]*`. If it's not, set `LANG=C` and try it.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '[[:alnum:]](#c8).[STFWMfWM][OUAHER][0-9]' '${(L)f}'
```

That will take of checking for potential conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Simple script `rename-lower`for current dir, if `rename` command is not working you can change in mv.

```
#/bin/bash
# script to replace all upper case to lower case
for i in *
do
        d=$(echo ${i} |tr [:upper:] [:lower:]);
        if [ ${d} != ${i} ]
        then
                echo "renaming:" ${i} ${d}
                rename ${i} ${d} ${i}
#               mv ${i} ${d}
        fi
done
```

Example

```
$ ls
tmp.EwcM2s6kfU  tmp.kcUX6rtjiu  tmp.kzpqLvWcnQ  tmp.N1H8bLt1at

$ rename-lower
renaming: tmp.EwcM2s6kfU  tmp.ewcm2s6kfu
renaming: tmp.kcUX6rtjiu  tmp.kcux6rtjiu
renaming: tmp.kzpqLvWcnQ  tmp.kzpqlvwcnq
renaming: tmp.N1H8bLt1at  tmp.n1h8blt1at
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `mv` command doesn't work as intended because what happens is that the shell expands the wildcards and the result is a single list of file names which is passed to `mv`. The syntax of `mv` is `mv SOURCE1 SOURCE2 … DESTINATION`, i.e. all the arguments except the last one are file names to be moved to the destination. `mv` does not support pattern-based renaming.

If you have the `prename` utility, you can use it to rename files by running Perl code on each name. The syntax is `prename PERL-CODE FILENAME1 FILENAME2 …`. The file name is in the variable `$_`, and the function `lc` converts its argument into lowerecase, so you can use the following code:

```
prename '$_ = lc($_)' /home/imp/hpt/outbound/[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z].[STFWMfWM][OUAHER][0-9]
```

If you don't have this utility, you can download a version from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3A%3ATussle).

Alternatively, you can do the renaming in the shell, with a loop. In bash, you can use `${x,,}` to get the value of `x` converted to lowercase.

```
for x in /home/imp/hpt/outbound/[0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z][0-9A-Z].[STFWMfWM][OUAHER][0-9]; do
  mv "$x" "${x,,}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```
    for f in *; do mv -T "$f" "$(echo $f | tr [A-Z] [a-z])"; done
```

It would be interesting, what the problems are with my solution.